# Running python scripts from Windows command line using Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, command-line, windows-xp, enthought

I am trying to use a .bat file to run python scripts on Windows XP -- I have just installed Enthought Canopy 32-bit and have changed the path to reflect the python interpreters true location. I can run python commands just fine using the canopy command line and thus after changing the cd, from the windows command line as well. However, I am unable to run a python file from a batch file and cannot figure out why. Every time I try, it merely opens up the file in the canopy editor instead of running the file.

What is the easiest way to fix this? I used the EPD distribution for a while prior to canopy being released, and that was much easier since it just installed python in its own directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article "[Make Canopy Python be your default Python i.e. on your PATH](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-)"

Comment: Thank you for that link. I am (now) able to change to the correct path...previously I couldn't find it because it was a hidden folder. I will edit my question to make more sense now..

Comment: Please give more detail. Do you mean that when you have "python myprog.py" in your batch file, then "myprog.py" is opened in the canopy editor?